# Player rotation using relative mouse movement instead of absolute

Tags: 3d, mathematics, rotation, mouse

I'm working on a twin stick shooter where the player looks at the mouse cursor. Like most I use the absolute mouse position and the player's position to determine the direction and derive an angle. This works great. However I recently discovered WM_INPUT which allows you to take advantage of higher DPI mouse movements, the values it provides are relative so a 'look at' type of solution does not work anymore.

Simply rotating the player based on a single axis does not feel right, since if you keep scrolling left the player would eventually rotate 360 degrees. I also tried to accumulate and scale the relative mouse movements and clamp them to -1 through 1 like gamepad thumb values, this works alright but feels a bit limiting in terms of full use of the higher sensitivity.

Does anyone have any insights into implementing top down player rotation using relative mouse movements?

Comment: Can you just use a virtual cursor object and use the relative movement to move the virtual cursor?

Comment: I tried this, however a virtual cursor needs to be visible for it to feel right. It falls apart once the distance from the player gets too large. Is there a solution for that? Clamping feels wrong.

Comment: You can display a graphic at the virtual cursor position. Clamping the virtual cursor inside the screen/window boundaries seems like a perfectly acceptable solution to me.